# SettingsPane not found in Windows 10 build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am building a new Windows 10 UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app using Visual Studio 2015.  Actually I am porting my Windows 8.1 app, but I did so by creating a whole new project and manually pulling in each class.

My app is failing to build with the following error:

The type or namespace name 'SettingsPane' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The C# file in question does have a **using** statement for **Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings**, and I also get the error even if I try to fully qualify SettingsPane as Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.aspx), SettingsPane should be available to Win10 apps, in the namespace I mentioned.

So the question is: why is my app failing to build?  Am I missing a dll, or just not understanding something else?

Answer (score 2):

The remark at the top of the document clears it up:

> [SettingsPane may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows
>   10. Instead of using a SettingsPane, integrate settings options into the app experience. For more info, see [Guidelines for app setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770544.aspx)s.]

Instead of using [SettingsPane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.aspx), make sure that you build native support for settings within the app itself.

Comment: There is no point registering with the settings pane in a Windows 10 app because there is no charms bar any more, so no way to open the settings pane.

Comment: Thank you for the answers Den & Raymond.  I was confused because the statement you quoted says "AFTER Windows 10".  The documentation says that it actually IS available in Windows 10, and even outlines the requirements for Windows 10 near the bottom of the page.  So maybe the doc is out of date.  I assume Win 10 must have a solution at least for running existing Win 8/8.1 apps that have StatusPanes.  And yes I understand a new Win 10 app should implement a settings page within the app, but I was hoping to migrate my existing code forward then deal with that later.  Appears not to be an option.

Comment: As noted in the documentation you linked, you need to add a reference to Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationsSettingsContract. That will give you access to the SettingsPane object, but be aware that it doesn't do anything.

Comment: on the win 8.1 store you had to actually include a privacy url in this SettingsPane, to get past app review. Now it's all just vanished. That should be good. We shall see what happens on app review now...

Comment: I'm having the same issue in a totally blank project using javascript. It shows an eval() line but not where it's sourcing the call so I can remove it.. Very frustrating..