# I am getting an error - The type or namespace name 'SettingsPane' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: uwp

I am trying to port the existing 8.1 app to UWP.

I am getting the following error: `The type or namespace name 'SettingsPane' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here is a function that is similar to the functions where I get this error:

```
void MainPage_Legal(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("legal", "Legal", OpenLegal));
    }.
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888429/settingspane-not-found-in-windows-10-build

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the SettingsPane documentation page from Microsoft:

> [SettingsPane may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 10. Instead of using a SettingsPane, integrate settings options into the app experience. For more info, see Guidelines for app settings.]

[SettingsPane Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.aspx)

[The Guidelines for app settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/app-settings/guidelines-for-app-settings)

I hope it helps a litte bit!

Comment: thanks sean but i need the implementation......The guidelines arent of any use to me